# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters in ReasonML/Ocaml

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ocaml

LeetCode Problems **3. Longest substring without repeating characters**

> Given a string, find the length of the **longest substring** without repeating characters.
>
> Examples:
>
> > Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc",  length 3.
> >
> > Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", length 1.
> >
> > Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", length 3. Note that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.

I did the question in ReasonML. However, I use a lot of `if` statement, it is an inappropriate coding style in function programming. Please feel free to comment, how to modify the source as functional programming oriented e.g. type-driven development, pattern matching, etc.

```
 let explode = s => List.init(String.length(s), String.get(s));

 module LongestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharacters: {
    let longestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharacters: string => int;
    let run: unit => unit;
  } = {
    let longestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharacters = l1 => {
      let ll = explode(l1);
      let myQueue = Queue.create();
      let rec aux = (queue, x: char, xs: list(char), ceil: int, counter: int) => {
        switch (xs) {
        | [] => ceil
        | [h, ...t] =>
          if (Queue.is_empty(queue) === false) {
            if (h != x) {
              if (h != Queue.top(queue)) {
                Queue.push(h, queue);
                aux(
                  queue,
                  h,
                  t,
                  ceil > counter ? ceil : ceil + 1,
                  counter + 1,
                );
              } else {
                let _c = Queue.pop(queue);
                aux(queue, h, t, ceil, counter - 1);
              };
            } else {
              Queue.clear(queue);
              aux(queue, '@', [h, ...t], ceil, 0);
            };
          } else {
            Queue.push(h, queue);
            aux(queue, h, t, ceil > counter ? ceil : ceil + 1, counter + 1);
          }
        };
      };
      aux(myQueue, '@', ll, 0, 0);
    };

    let run = () => {
      Printf.printf(
        "longestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharacters : %d\n",
        longestSubstringWithoutRepeatingCharacters("abcabcbb"),
      );
    };
  };
```